# How to install php 5.3 when 5.4 is already installed?

Tags: php

The usual mistake: I developed with the newest PHP version, while server has 5.3 ... and some errors appears.
Now I want to install Php 5.3 too, but Im affraid it would spoil the settings of 5.4, the registry entries, etc.... in other words, I want to be able to choose to start 5.3 or 5.4.... how to do it?

Comment: What server? Local or remote?

Comment: Linux, 5.3, and remote, we cant change that. Im using Windows, with 5.4

Comment: You mean you want to install 5.3 on your dev machine?

Comment: On Linux you'd simply install the different PHP version in a different directory/prefix. I imagine something like this exists for Windows too, and possibly even tools that help you manage multiple installations of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can recall php doesn't put anything of importance in the registry. The thing
that determines what version of php will be used is your server config (apache?).

I don't have a windows box nearby right now, but what I would investigate is if there are any
environment variables that are set, e.g. to pear directory. If you can't find
anything like that then you should be quite safe and the config of each php should reside
in files in the respective directory.